# Laravel route is not letting me load my assets properly

Tags: laravel, routes

In my laravel 9 project, when I have more than 4 '/' in my route, the project doesn't assets properly for that page. Because it includes the first keyword of my defined route.

For example: If I define a get route:

example.com/word1/word2/word3/word4/word5

In this case, all my other related routes such as my image links, where I've used route('/images/..')

The application loads the link: example.com/word1/images/... instead of example.com/images/...

I used '/' to solve this.

Comment: For static files that live in public directory, you should use [asset helper](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-asset) i.e. `asset('images/default.png')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a relative URL (e.g. /images/example.jpg), the browser will interpret it as being relative to the current page's URL. So if you're on a page with a URL like example.com/word1/word2/word3/word4/word5, then the relative URL /images/example.jpg will be interpreted as example.com/word1/word2/word3/word4/images/example.jpg.

To avoid this issue, you can use absolute URLs instead of relative URLs. An absolute URL includes the full URL, including the protocol (e.g. https://) and domain name. In your case, you can use the URL helper function to generate absolute URLs for your assets, like this: This will generate an absolute URL that includes only the domain name and the path to the asset, regardless of the current page's URL

```
<img src="{{ url('/images/example.jpg') }}" alt="Example">
```